# How do I set up a microsite, what are my options?

Tags: joomla, web, subdomain

I'm currently working on Joomla 3.4.3 hosting via an LCN domain.

I need to create a microsite to promote and event and I haven't any experience with setting one up.

I just want to know whether it's easiest to do it via a sub-domain with another copy of Joomla and my template on it? Or is that a bit overkill, is there an easier way?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Do you need a microsite or a landing page? I'm asking because creating a landing page is very easy and SEO safe. Microsites can be a lot more labor intensive, and if they're done as a means to funnel traffic to a bigger site, that can make some search engines angry.

Does the site stand completely on its own apart from your website, or is it going to funnel traffic to it?

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me - sorry about the time taken.
I think overall after reviewing your content, it would be better and more economic to go with a landing page.

Thanks for your help.